# QGIS Training Manual Vector Menu

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, training

I just (December 12, 2018) downloaded the training manual and data. I'm trying to get started but I cant find the first part to download the OpenStreetMap part.

"In the Vector menu dropdown, select OpenStreetMap -> Download Data. You can then manually enter the co-ordinates of the region you wish to use, or you can use an existing layer to set the co-ordinates."

I see the Vector menu on the top ribbon, but the dropdown does not have the right option. I cruised around but didn't see a way to add it.

Comment: You can find the QGIS 3 training manual under https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using QGIS 2.18.x, you can find `Vector -> OpenStreetMap -> Download Data`:

[image]

However, if you are using QGIS 3.4 or 3.X in general, OpenStreetMap is not there, which I assume this is the QGIS version that you currently have:

[image]

If you want to download OpenStreetMap, you can use some plugins such as [OSM Downloader](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/OSMDownloader/) but personally I didn't test it.

Comment: Yes I just dl'ed 3.4.2, thanks. I guess I can create my own .osm file, but I wanted to follow along with the instructions. Or do you think I could find QGIS 2.18?

Comment: @BruceBowers If you want to follow the manual instructions, then it is better to download QGIS 2.18.

Comment: Older versions of QGIS can be downloaded here: http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/. Click on your operating system and scroll down until you find version 2.18.26. Here's a direct link to download QGIS 2.18.26 for 64-bit Windows: http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/windows/QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.18.26-1-Setup-x86_64.exe

Comment: The `QuickOSM` plugin is a lot better. You can filter for data you want, or take the `All OSM` query in the `My Queries` tab to get everything inside the map canvas.

Comment: @AndreJ I didn't know about QuickOSM. Thanks for sharing. I will give it a try.